# Solving a Catalan-like recursion of polynomials, related to the KdV energies

Tags: co.combinatorics, ap.analysis-of-pdes, binomial-coefficients, integrable-systems, catalan-numbers

I am working on a PDE problem. The goal is to connect the higher order energies of the Gross-Pitaevskii equation to those of the Korteweg-de-Vries equation. As these higher order energies are recursively defined polynomials, combinatorics come into play. I have determined a key combinatorial problem, a certain cancellation of recursively defined polynomials, and I know all the right coefficients to cancel them out in the way I want, having checked up to n = 11. I just can't to prove it. If one of you guys finds a solution, perhaps we can collaborate on a paper.

I will now present the problem and some of my approaches. I use $\land$ to denote the minimum and $\lor$ the maximum. I write $n \text{ mod } 2$ to mean $1$ if $n$ is odd, and $0$ otherwise.

**The Problem.**

We first define some coefficients:

\begin{align*}
    A(n, j) &= C_{n-j} \sqrt{2}^{1+j-n} (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{j}{2} \rfloor} ,
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    P(l, n) &= (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} (2 \sqrt{2})^{l - n} \begin{pmatrix} 
        - \frac12 + \lfloor \frac{l}{2} \rfloor - n \\ 
        l - n 
    \end{pmatrix} ,
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    Q(l, n) &= (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{l-1}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor} (2 \sqrt{2})^{l - n} \begin{pmatrix}
        - \frac12 - \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \\ 
        l - n
    \end{pmatrix} .
\end{align*}

Here
\begin{equation*}
    C_n = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}
\end{equation*}
are the Catalan numbers.

Now consider the polynomial ring $\mathcal{R} = \mathbb{C}[G_0^0, G_1^0, G_1^2]$.
We define polynomials $G_n^k \in \mathcal{R}$ for $n \geq 0$ and $k \in [0, 2n]$. If $k$ is odd, then we also set $G_n^k = 0$. For even $k \geq 4$ and $n \geq 1$, we set
\begin{align*}
    G_{n+1}^k &= \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{m=0 \lor (k+2j-2-2n)}^{(2j) \land (k-2)} (n \text{ mod } 2 - (-1)^j) G_j^m G_{n-j}^{k-2-m} + \sum_{j=0}^n A(n, j) G_j^k \\
\end{align*}

The hypothesis is now any of the three following statements, which are more or less equivalent: Let $l \geq 0$ and $k \in [0, 2 l]$ be an even number.

1. Define
   \begin{align*}
       E_l^k = \sum_{n = \frac{k}{2}}^l P(l, n) \, G_n^k.
   \end{align*}
   Then
   \begin{equation*}
       l \geq k+2 \Longrightarrow E_l^k = 0
   \end{equation*}
2. We may define the same $E_l^k$ by
   \begin{align*}
       E_l^k &= G_l^k + \sum_{n = \frac{k}{2}}^{(l - 1) \land (k + 1)} Q(l, n) \, E_n^k.
   \end{align*}
   Then
   \begin{equation*}
       l \geq k+2 \Longrightarrow E_l^k = 0
   \end{equation*}
3. Combining 1. and 2. leads to the following claim:
   If we fix a $k$, then the recursion in $n$ is solved by this exact formula, which depends on the first $k+1$ terms:
   \begin{equation*}
       l \geq k + 2 \Longrightarrow G_l^k = - \sum_{j = \frac{k}{2}}^{k + 1} G_j^k \sum_{n = j}^{k + 1} Q(l, n) P(n, j) \,.
   \end{equation*}
   Note also that
   \begin{equation*}
   \sum_{n = j}^l Q(l, n) P(n, j) = \delta_{l, n}
   \end{equation*}
   This means that the formula also holds trivially for $l < k + 2$, it is "consistent".

**My Approaches.**

The first thing I tried was to show 3. by induction. I used the definition of the $G_n^k$, applied formula 3. to the terms that appeared and tried to regroup everything to obtain formula 3. for my current term. I could not make this work, as there are many terms and they can't obviously be regrouped into what you want.

Then I tried generating functions and actually had some success.

**Generating Functions.**

Define
\begin{align*}
U_n^k = (-1)^n G_{2n}^{2k} \qquad \qquad k \in [0, 2n] \qquad \qquad U_0^0 \text{ given}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
V_n^k = (-1)^n G_{2n+1}^{2k} \qquad \qquad k \in [0, 2n+1] \qquad \qquad V_0^0, V_0^1 \text{ given}
\end{align*}

Then this solves

\begin{align*}
U_{n+1}^k &= - 2 \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{m=0 \lor (k-1-2n+2j)}^{(2j+1) \land (k-1)} V_j^m U_{n-j}^{k-1-m} + \sum_{j=0}^n C_{2n-2j} \sqrt{2}^{1+2j-2n} V_j^k
+ \sum_{j=0}^n C_{1+2n-2j} \sqrt{2}^{2j-2n} U_j^k 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
V_{n+1}^k &= - \sum_{j=0}^{n+1} \sum_{m=0 \lor (k-3-2n+2j)}^{(2j) \land (k-1)} U_j^m U_{n-j+1}^{k-1-m}
- \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{m=0 \lor (k-2-2n+2j)}^{(2j+1) \land (k-1)} V_j^m V_{n-j}^{k-1-m} + \sum_{j=0}^{n+1} C_{2n+2-2j} \sqrt{2}^{2j-2n-1} U_j^k
+ \sum_{j=0}^n C_{2n+1-2j} \sqrt{2}^{2j-2n} V_j^k
\end{align*}

We want to rewrite this in terms of the generating functions
\begin{align*}
u(y, z) = \sum_{n, k} U_n^k y^n z^k \qquad \qquad v(y, z) = \sum_{n, k} V_n^k y^n z^k .
\end{align*}

I haven't checked this computation many times yet, but I obtained:

\begin{align*}
u(y, z) = u(y, z) \Big(2 - \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}} - \sqrt{1 - 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}}\Big) + v(y, z) \sqrt{y} \Big(\sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}} - \sqrt{1 - 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}}\Big)
- 2 u(y, z) v(y, z) y z
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
v(y, z) = v(y, z) \Big(2 - \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}} - \sqrt{1 - 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}}\Big)  + u(y, z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \Big(\sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}} - \sqrt{1 - 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}}\Big) - u(y, z)^2 z - v(y, z)^2 y z
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, I don't see how to rewrite one of the hypotheses 1., 2., or 3. in terms of these generating functions.

I would be very happy if anyone can tell me how difficult one should expect this problem to be, or maybe even solve it.

Comment: Are $\vee$ and $\wedge$ bitwise OR and AND? Or maybe $\max$ and $\min$?

Comment: It is the min and max. I clarified it in the post, thanks. The limits of the sum over m can actually be dropped if you just set $G_n^k = 0$ for every "illegal" pair of $(n, k)$.

Comment: Even with the limits, I think you need to define $G_0^k = 0$ for even $k > 0$. But it seems empirically that this then gives $G_n^k = 0$ if $k > 2n$.

Comment: In the definition of $G^k_{n+1}$, there is a comma (",") between $A(n,j)$ and $G^k_j$; is this a specific notation or just a typo?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: If $k > 0$ then $k \not\in [0, 2*0]$, so $(n, k)$ is not a pair where $G_n^k$ is defined, i.e. we set it to zero. However if I put the limits correctly, such terms should not appear. The recursive definition only applies for $k \geq 4$ though, as the previous cases $k = 0$ and $k = 2$ are already given, i.e. the assumed variables from which we build polynomials. I'll add that.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks, that is a typo.

Comment: I don't see where $k=0$ and $k=2$ are given for $n > 1$. For the other "out of bounds" values, it seems largely to have been a bug I must have introduced when trying to work with half-k, but the sum $\sum_{j=0}^n A(n, j) G_j^k$ does need to limit $j \ge \frac k2$ if you want to leave "illegal" values undefined rather than 0.